# Qt - Loading image with wrong extension

Tags: python, qt, pyside, file-extension, qimage

I'm currently working on a Qt program that works with images that are supplied by the users. One problem I've run into is that a lot of images are saved with the wrong extension - e.g. an image is saved in JPG format but has a PNG extension.

Qt doesn't seem to deal well with this. When I load an image like this into a QImage, the QImage fails to load. I've been looking through the docs, but I haven't come across anything relating to this.

Other programs I've used are able to correctly identify the image as a JPG despite the PNG extension, so there should be no reason for Qt to be unable to do this, but I'm not having any luck.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by using a QImageReader. An example is shown below using PySide. 
First I created an instance of QImageReader and set it to read the format from the content.

```
image_reader = QtGui.QImageReader()
image_reader.setDecideFromContent(True)
```

This setting tells the reader to only look at the image's data to determine its format and not the extension.

Then I set the filename to the filename of the image I wanted to load and called read().

```
image_reader.setFileName(file_path_here)
image = image_reader.read()
```

Read returns a QImage object, so I proceeded with the rest of my code from there.