# Qt cant load any file QImage

Tags: c++, qt, file, qt5

Here is my code:

```
QImage cover(":/Images/cover-placeholder.jpg");

if (cover.isNull()) {
    cout << "File load Error!" << endl;
}
```

Whichever file I upload, it always throws an error. I have also tried writing the absolute path of the file and it still giving error. I also tried this code:

```
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName();

QImage temp;
if (!temp.load(fileName)) {
   cout << "Cant load" << endl;
}
```

and it also doesn't work either. What is the problem?

qrc file:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>Images/cover-placeholder.jpg</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Comment: Check your path, There is a C or D missing (or whatever letter your drive has)

Comment: @RoQuOTriX doesn't work anyway

Comment: According to the first code you have the image in a .qrc, is that correct?

Comment: @eyllanesc yes, and i tried use "qrc:/Images/cover-placeholder.jpg" but image doesn't loading

Comment: @nick_redwill show your .qrc

Comment: Also try with:  `QImageReader reader("/fullpath/of/cover-placeholder.jpg");`  `QImage img = reader.read()` `if(img.isNull()) {qDebug() << reader.errorString(); }`

Comment: @eyllanesc <RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>Images/cover-placeholder.jpg</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>

Comment: @nick_redwill add the .qrc  in your post

Comment: @eyllanesc reader.errorString() gives "formatUnsupported image"

Comment: So your .jpg is corrupt or not a .jpg. Some time ago a user pointed out that he could not load an image in the .png format downloaded from the internet, but after analyzing the image it had a .jpg format with the suffix .png

Comment: @eyllanesc Thank you so match! I converted image to png and it's work fine!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Qt - Loading image with wrong extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29724724/qt-loading-image-with-wrong-extension)

Answer (score 0):

Some images downloaded from the internet have suffixes that do not correspond to the format, and QImage uses the suffix to detect the type of image, so I recommend verifying that the suffix is the same format.

To get the load cause of a QImage then a QImageReader must be used:

```cpp
QImageReader reader("/fullpath/of/cover-placeholder.jpg"); 
QImage img = reader.read() 
if(img.isNull())
{
    qDebug() << reader.errorString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you are deploying a Qt application you should deploy the image format plugins under app_dir/imageformats directory. Plugins are: qjpeg.dll, qgif.dll, qsvg.dll etc.